# wpf Popup Lightbox effect on window

Tags: wpf, popup, window, lightbox, effect

I am using following code to set gray light effect on window when I open a popup. It works fine but it basically reloads all controls or refreshes the main window .

Especially this line: `currentWindow.Content = lightboxGrid;`

```
Window currentWindow = Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>()
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(MAIN_WINDOW_NAME));

Grid lightboxGrid = new Grid();
object currentWindowContent = currentWindow.Content;
currentWindow.Content = null;
lightboxGrid.Children.Add(new ContentControl() 
{ 
    Content = currentWindowContent 
});

// now add the grid that will "black out" the content
Grid blackoutGrid = new Grid();
blackoutGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
lightboxGrid.Children.Add(blackoutGrid);
blackoutGrid.Opacity = 0.0; // start fully transparent
blackoutGrid.Loaded += blackoutGrid_Loaded;
currentWindow.Content = lightboxGrid;
this._lightboxEffectApplied = true;
```

What could be the option to have the same effect without refreshing the main window or reloading the controls?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your main window has a Grid as its layout root (even if all the content is in the first cell), then you could add this blackoutGrid as a child to that grid and it will display above the other elements without messing with the original visual tree structure.

In this case, the Content of your Window would be a Grid, and you would add your blackoutGrid to that Grid, and remove it when you are done.

The way you are writing this seems to be a little against object-oriented practice.  Technically it should be your Main Window that has the ability to display a lightbox effect.